# PHP Infine Loop Problem

Tags: php, sockets

```
function httpGet( $url, $followRedirects=true ) {
    global $final_url;
    $url_parsed = parse_url($url);
    if ( empty($url_parsed['scheme']) ) {
        $url_parsed = parse_url('http://'.$url);
    }
    $final_url = $url_parsed;

    $port = $url_parsed["port"];
    if ( !$port ) {
        $port = 80;
    }
    $rtn['url']['port'] = $port;

    $path = $url_parsed["path"];
    if ( empty($path) ) {
        $path="/";
    }
    if ( !empty($url_parsed["query"]) ) {
        $path .= "?".$url_parsed["query"];
    }
    $rtn['url']['path'] = $path;

    $host = $url_parsed["host"];
    $foundBody = false;

    $out = "GET $path HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: $host\r\n";
    $out .= "User-Agent:      Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1) Gecko/20061010 Firefox/2.0\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

    if ( !$fp = @fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30) ) {
        $rtn['errornumber'] = $errno;
        $rtn['errorstring'] = $errstr;

    }
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!@feof($fp)) {

        $s = @fgets($fp, 128);
        if ( $s == "\r\n" ) {
            $foundBody = true;
            continue;
        }
        if ( $foundBody ) {
            $body .= $s;
        } else {
            if ( ($followRedirects) && (stristr($s, "location:") != false) ) {
                $redirect = preg_replace("/location:/i", "", $s);
                return httpGet( trim($redirect) );
            }
            $header .= $s;
        }
    }

    fclose($fp);

    return(trim($body));
}
```

This code sometimes go infinite loop. What's wrong here?

Comment: Posting a giant block of code is not likely to get you any help. Reducing the amount of code to show the problem is best.

Comment: this function gets the html of a URL also does redirection.
Anybody have better function that does this?
file_get_contents with redirection???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a big, red warning box in the [`feof()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.feof.php):

> **Warning**
>
> If a connection opened by `fsockopen()` wasn't closed by the server, `feof()` will hang. To workaround this, see below example:
>
> Example #1 Handling timeouts with feof()
>
> ```
>     <?php
>         function safe_feof($fp, &start = NULL) {
>              $start = microtime(true); 
>              return feof($fp);
>         }   
>         /* Assuming $fp is previously opened by fsockopen() */
>
>         $start = NULL;
>         $timeout = ini_get('default_socket_timeout');
>
>         while(!safe_feof($fp, $start) && (microtime(true) - $start) < $timeout)
>         {
>           /* Handle */
>         }
>     ?>
> ```

---

Also you should only write to or read from the file pointer, if it is valid (what you are not doing, you just set an error message):
This leads to the second big red warning box:

> **Warning**
>
> If the passed file pointer is not valid you may get an infinite loop, because `feof()` fails to return `TRUE`.

Better would be:

```
$result = '';

if ( !$fp = @fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30) ) {
    $rtn['errornumber'] = $errno;
    $rtn['errorstring'] = $errstr;
}
else {
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!@feof($fp)) {
        //...
    }
    fclose($fp);
    $result = trim(body);
}
return $result;
```

---

A last remark: If you follow a redirect with

```
 if ( ($followRedirects) && (stristr($s, "location:") != false) ) {
     $redirect = preg_replace("/location:/i", "", $s);
     return httpGet( trim($redirect) );
 }
```

you never close the file pointer. I think better is:

```
 if ( ($followRedirects) && (stristr($s, "location:") != false) ) {
     $redirect = preg_replace("/location:/i", "", $s);
     $result = httpGet( trim($redirect) );
     break;
 }
 // ...
 return $result;
```

Comment: &start=NULL or $start=NULL ??

Answer (score 0):

feof will return false if the connection is still open in a tcp/ip stream.

Answer (score 0):

```
function httpGet( $url, $followRedirects=true ) {
[...]
                return httpGet( trim($redirect) );
}
```

Nothing prevents you from fetching the same URL again and again.